# Blazor WASM .Net5 Prerender Page Cannot Be Found

Tags: blazor, webassembly, .net-5

I have set up a basic WASM Hosted template and have converted to a Prerendered following

https://jonhilton.net/blazor-wasm-prerendering/#commento-login-box-container

and

https://chrissainty.com/prerendering-a-client-side-blazor-application/

All seems to work as expected, I can click on the nav links and it changes pages as expected.  However, I cannot directly navigate to a page via URL.  If i type in localhost:port/Counter i get a Localhost page cannot be found.   When I click the navlink for counter it shows the URL as localhost:port/Counter.

Why am I not able to directly navigate to the URL?

**EDITED:**

Here are some of the files to get an idea of whats going on.

Here is the Server Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

The changes here was to change the mappfallbacktofile of /_Host.   This was a new file added to the Server/Pages folder and is as follows

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorAppNet5WasmHosted.Client
@namespace BlazorAppNet5WasmHosted.Server.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>BlazorAppNet5WasmHosted</title>
        <base href="/" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="BlazorAppNet5WasmHosted.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
        <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Theres really nothing specifically to share.  Its the out of the box .Net5 Blazor App WebAssembly hosted model that has been setup with the new prerender as described in the above URL blog posts.   There isnt a specific code section to show, its really the entire project

Comment: It's depend how you setup it, so there's think to share : _host.cshtml, Statup.cs and blazor app Program.cs

Comment: Updated with the Server startup and _host files

Comment: enet that doesnt really answer my question.  I have it set up for prerender its the navigation to URLs directly that is failing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the server startup i had which change the Fallback to /_Host

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/_Host");
            });
```

However the issue is it should not be endpoint.MapFallbackToFile("_Host"); it should be endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");   That is was what causing the refresh to fail